# Is there a way to verify a common seed to a cumulative sequence of hashes with unknown repetitions between each value presented?

Tags: hash, cryptography

I am writing a variant of the Cuckoo Cycle that uses an adjacency list for presenting solutions from two pairs of 8 bit coordinates, and I am not having any problems finding what I think should be an optimal solver for it, that uses two pairs of head/tail binary search trees to keep track of possible solution nodes, reject (branches) nodes and a binary tree that keeps a list of the candidate cycles as they are being assembled (as I understand it, binary search trees shorten the amount of processing for finding duplicates), but I need to refine the verifier function for solutions.

I see in Cuckoo that there is some process by which it modifies the edges with XOR functions and masks to identify a valid cycle, but I have two issues.

One is that each hash is generated from the previous hash, starting with the nonce, and proving that all offered node/edge pairs are valid derivatives from the nonce seems to me to require the verifier to repeat the hash function each time checking for a match until it gets a hit, which could be up to several thousand, in the worst case. Is there some property that can be used to shortcut this identification process, since unlike protection against DoS, we are providing the salt of the hash?

Second is that even if the presented cycle is perfectly valid, it is possible that one or more of the node/edge pairs in the cycle has a duplicate coordinate. The hashes are 32 bits long, and each coordinate is 8 bits. The answer to this probably has some relation to the previous question also, as having the seed for a hash function is a known security risk because of collisions. So obviously, as well as verifying the nodes are part of a cycle in the lowest possible values in the finite field, I need a way to be sure that a pair does not overlap with another possible, and branching pair.

I will be studying the verifier closer in the Cuckoo Cycle implementation to see if I can figure out how the algorithm ensures it is not approving a cycle that actually has a branch (and thus is invalid), but I thought I'd pop the question on this site in case someone knows better the ways of recognising hashes from a common seed, and if there is any way to recognise a 50% collision between a given coordinate and another one.

---

Note: After thinking about it for a while, I realised that I could solve the 'fake cycle' with one or more nodes having a branch by simply splitting the heads and tails into separate hashes, subsequent (odd then even), such as Murmur3 16 bit hashes.

And further thinking about it, I realised that Cuckoo Cycle is actually a special type of hash collision search that seeks only collisions that occur only once in the low order of the finite field. I am devising a new scheme called Hummingbird, which instead will not target the smallest numbers (which is also the same thing done by hashcash) but instead will target the most proximate hashes in a chain to the seed nonce. This will mean that attempts to insert branched nodes in the graph of the solution will be discovered in the verification. Which will probably take about 2-5 seconds depending on how deep. These solutions could be eliminated by specifying a maximum hash chain length as part of the consensus.

Comment: This sounds more like a question you should be asking on a math or cryptography related stack exchange site.

Comment: Or bitcoin.stackexchanage.com which is more specialized in block chain tech.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about block chain / crypto without involving programming.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add that I answered my own question by realising that I am looking for, essentially, a hash collision, in my algorithm, and the simplest solution, with the least bit-twiddling was to make each coordinate a distinct hash in a hash chain (hash of nonce, then hash of hash, etc)

I didn't understand fully that Cuckoo Cycle is essentially a search for partial hash collisions, and when that dawned on me, I realised that the simple solution is to just make it into a search for hash collisions.

I have, from this realisation, moved very quickly forward to figuring out how my variation of Cuckoo can be much more simply implemented, as well as how to structure the B-tree based progressive search algorithm, the difficulty adjustment, and the rest.

I wasn't aware there was a stackexchange specialist site for math, or cryptography, or I would have posted it there instead. I studied FEC a few months ago and that opened the floodgates to a whole bunch of other ideas that led me to getting so worked up about Cuckoo Cycle. I believe I have generalised the Cuckoo Cycle into a generic, parameterisable graph theoretic proof of work and I will get back to finishing my implementation.

Thanks to everyone who submitted an answer, I will upvote as I deem correct, though I have zero or nearly zero rep, for what it's worth.